# Average case hardness of #SAT

Tags: counting-complexity, average-case-complexity

Is there anything known about the average case hardness of #SAT? Let’s say over a uniform distribution.

We know that in the worst case, it is #P-complete, but what can we say about an average instance of #SAT?

Comment: Over what distribution of instances?

Comment: It's not enough to say "uniform distribution".  Over what set of instances?  Note that whether a random formula is likely to be satisfiable *at all* depends on how the number of clauses relates to the number of variables. Search scholar.google.com for, e.g., "random SAT threshold".  https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22&q=random+SAT+threshold&btnG=

Comment: FWIW, some variants of computing the *Permanent* of a given matrix are known to be both #P-complete, and as hard in the average case as the worst case.